# android:imeActionLabel and android:imeOptions not respected on all devices.

Tags: android

I have the following definition for an edit text:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/password"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                        android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                        android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/loginColorPrimaryDark" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

On the Action button I want to initiate login:

```
 edt_password.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(textView.getWindowToken(),
                            InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN);
                    attemptLogin();


                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

While in a Nexus 5 device all is working properly, in a Sony device I get the following:

[image]

So neither the `android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"` nor the `android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"` is getting respected.

To my amazement, I have not specified this by myself, I had chosen a Login Activity in the project template while creating the project in Android Studio. Seems it is broken!

Answer (score 1):

try using the below code... for me it is working for all the devices.. hope it will help you

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:imeActionLabel="SIGN UP"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color"/>

confirmPassword.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
                    attemptLogin();
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```